# How can the levels of an asymmetric double well be understood qualitatively?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential-energy, quantum-tunneling

[image]

Consider the potential energy profile above (blue). There are two minima which can be thought of as wells, one much deeper than the other. In the diagram there are a few energy levels that I drew in too.

I understand that if a state with energy $E_1$ exists, then it will be a bound state, because there are no states elsewhere for the particle to tunnel into so the electron (or whatever) would just sit in that level, and likely be highly localized near the position of the minimum of that well.

I also understand that $E_3$ is quasi-bound. There is a discrete level inside the well, but eventually the particle will tunnel out through the barrier into the continuum of scattering states there.

**Question**: What about the energy level at $E_2$? In that energy regime there is another well which the particle could conceivably tunnel into. But my question is how to view such a phenomenon qualitatively?

Is it correct to find the different energy levels in the two different wells and then tunnelling only occurs if there is an energy level in each well that has the energy $E_2$? Or do you instead follow the usual procedure of calculating the wavefunctions in each region, matching them, and then finding the eigenvalues? The latter seems right to me, and if that is the case it would seem to suggest that it is only possible to have an energy level in the first well if there is also a level of the same energy in the second well (indeed they would be the same state, and the particle would just oscillate between them a measurement of the position of the particle at any time would tell us it is in either one well or the other).

My problem with this is that I have heard people say things in seminars before which would suggest that given two wells the correct way to proceed is to instead find the levels in each of them, and then see if any of them match up, in which case tunnelling will occur.

Thanks.

Comment: In the "correct procedure" of course the energy has to be same in both the wells which is a consequence of solving the schroedinger equation for both the wells as one single potential. Solving them separately makes sense when the separation between the wells is very large such that the wave function has nearly zero probability density in the classically disallowed region.

Comment: I can think of three approaches to this problem: a) time independent perturbation theory; b) the variational principle; c) WKB.  None of them will give you the full answer to your problem.  Each yields various insights.  Regarding (a), one can frame your question in terms of the transition between when degenerate perturbation theory applies and when second order perturbation theory applies.